# Generic ForEach Method that accepts a List and Value of same Type and Changes List Member Properties

Tags: c#, generics, foreach

I have multiple classes with the same property. I want to create a single method that would serve the same purpose for each individual class.

**Example:**

```
 private void RefreshSelection<T>(ObservableCollection<T> itemList, T selectedItem)
    {
        foreach (var item in itemList)
        {
            item.IsSelected = selectedItem.Equals(item);
        }
    }
```

As expected, I recieve this error:

```
'T' does not contain a definition for 'IsSelected' and no extension method 'IsSelected' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have tried to find a useful answer but can only find examples of retrieving the property value, not changing it. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface called `IIsSelected`

```
public interface IIsSelected
{
   bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Then implement this interface on your classes which has the `IsSelected`property:

```
public class MySelectableClass : IIsSelected
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Update your method to:

```
private void RefreshSelection<T>(ObservableCollection<T> itemList, T selectedItem)
where T: IIsSelected
{
    foreach (var item in itemList)
    {
        item.IsSelected = selectedItem.Equals(item);
    }
}
```

The method will only except any type which implements the `IIsSelected` interface and the compiler won't throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `Interface` and decorate your classes that support IsSelected

```
public interface ISelectable
{
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class MyAwesomeClass : ISelectable
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    // Blah
}

private void RefreshSelection<T>(ObservableCollection<ISelectable> itemList, T selectedItem) 
    where T : class, ISelectable
{
    foreach (var item in itemList)
    {
        item.IsSelected = selectedItem.Equals(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are great, but occasionally there are situations where you cannot decorate existing classes with an interface. For example,

- the class definitions are in 3rd-party DLLs,
- you do not have permission from the team leader.

For these situations, move the property-set outside your function, passing it in as a lambda function instead:

```
private void RefreshSelection<T>(ObservableCollection<T> itemList, T selectedItem,
                                 Action<T, bool> setSelected)
{
    foreach (T item in itemList)
    {
        setSelected(item, selectedItem.Equals(item));
    }
}
```

and call it this way:

```
RefreshSelection(itemList, selectedItem, (i, newValue) => 
{
    i.IsSelected = newValue;
});
```

This is a standard technique for reusing code - extensively used by Linq and jQuery.